# Time Series plot.ts and x label

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have .csv file with quarters in first col (like 200901, 200902 etc) or I can have them as a row names. In other cols I have some common statistical data (like inflation rate 102.5; 101.5 etc).
The problem is that function plot.ts doesn't show the quarters in x label. Althoug I see nice 7 plots in one card.
My code is simple:

```
require(ggplot2)
plot.ts(abc, xlab = abc$quarters)
```

abc - my file with data, abc$quarters - col with number of quarters.

Maybe other function will be better here, but I get annoyed just for thinking it's very close to quite an easy solution.

Comment: `plot.ts` is not a ggplot function.  ggplot2 doesn't work well with timeseries.  They need to be coerced into a dataframe (or tibble).

Comment: Please add some data in order to make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 2):

As comments say, `plot.ts` isn't a ggplot2 function. Here's an example of what you may be looking for in ggplot2:

```
library(stocks)
library(tidyverse)

getSymbols("AMZN", src="yahoo", from="2016-07-01")

data.frame(AMZN) %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  mutate(
    rowname = as.Date(rowname, format="%Y-%m-%d")
  ) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(rowname, AMZN.Close)) +
  scale_x_date(expand = expand_scale(0), minor_breaks = NULL,
               date_breaks = "3 months", date_labels = "%m-%Y") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image: plot]

I'd suggest working with ggplot2 functions for plotting time series over something like `plot.ts` since it'd likely be more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers, they lead me to the following solution:

```
 dane_2$abc2    dane_2$abc3   dane_2$abc4 
[1,]    103.5        19.9         37.3
[2,]    103.4        19.5         35.2
[3,]    103.0        25.1         34.7

View(dane_2) 
# In dane_2$abc1 I have own numbers of quarters like 20094, so I skip it.
tseries <- ts(dane_2[ ,-1], start = c(2009, 4), frequency = 4)
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(tseries)
```